# how to divide previously union all into multiple inserts in a for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Sorry if the title is confusing

I have a query that is something like this:

```
Declare
cursor xy is
select yr from calendar;

BEGIN
for rec1 in xy loop
insert into new_table
Select yr, month, name, position from table_1
where yr = rec1.yr
union all
Select yr, month, name, position from table_2
where yr = rec1.yr
union all
Select yr, month, name, position from table_3
where yr = rec1.yr;
commit;
end loop;
end;
```

but I want to divide the union alls into multiple insert intos,
so something like

```
BEGIN
for rec1 in xy loop
insert into new_table
Select yr, month, name, position from table_1
where yr = rec1.yr;
commit;
insert into new_table
Select yr, month, name, position from table_2
where yr = rec1.yr
commit;
.
.
etc
```

but when I try this it runs for so long and goes into time out. While the previous would only take a couple of minutes. So probably there's something wrong with the query, so any help is appreciated

Comment: First of all, remove `COMMIT`s out of the loop.

Secondly, you have solution which works well and does the job correctly. So, why do you insist on rewriting it into something that works worse than that and you aren't satisfied with it?

Comment: By the way, [indenting code](https://codehs.gitbooks.io/introcs/content/Programming-with-Karel/how-to-indent-your-code.html) makes it a lot more readable and helps you avoid syntax errors.